# $P^1 × A^1$, $P^2 $− {∗}, and $A^2 $− {∗} are non-isomorphic varieties and are neither projective nor affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to show $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{A}^1$, $\mathbb{A}^2 − \{\text{pt}\}$, and $\mathbb{A}^2 − \{\text{pt}\}$ are non-isomorphic varieties and are neither projective nor affine?

My idea is to find out the regular function of these spaces, which should prove they are not isomorphic. I know $A^2$-{∗} has same regular function of $A^2$ and also know why it is not affine. But how about the other two guys? I have no idea about the regular function of them.

Answer (score 1):

The space of global regular algebraic functions on $\mathbb{P}^n\times$Spec$A$ for any ring $A$ (commutative with 1) is always $A$ (Hartshorne AG II.5). Since $\mathbb{A}^1=$Spec$k[x]$, the space of global regular algebraic functions on $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{A}^1$ is $k[x]$ (this is easy to prove directly using the standard open affine cover). The space of regular functions does not change upon removing a codimension 2 subvariety (Hartog's theorem), so the space of regular functions on $\mathbb{P}^2-pt$ is the same as that of $\mathbb{P}^2$.

For proving not projective, a regular function on a projective variety must be constant.

For proving not affine, an affine variety is determined by the ring of regular functions on it.

Comment: So how to prove $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{A}^1$ is not affine and $\mathbb P^2- p$ is not projective. Actually, could you please also explain more about how to find the regular function of $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{A}^1$ directly?

Comment: A regular function on $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{A}^1$ is given by a regular function on $(\mathbb{P}^1-NorthPole)\times\mathbb{A}^1$ and a regular function on $(\mathbb{P}^1-SouthPole)\times\mathbb{A}^1$ such that the two functions are the same when restricted to the intersection. So you have elements of $R_1=k[X_1,Y]$ and $R_2=k[X_2,Y]$ whose images are the same in $R_3:=(R_1)_{X_1}$ (that is, $R_1$ localized at $X_1$), where the map $R_2\rightarrow R_3$ is $X_2\mapsto 1/X_1, Y\mapsto Y$. What does that say about these elements?